# How to get the Channel Form » Grid » Relations options?

Tags: channel-entries, safecracker, relationships, grid

I'm doing a customized Channel Form but I'm having trouble getting the options in the relations within my grid...

MENU (title)
» DISH (text on grid)
» » INGREDIENT (relationships on grid)

But in my Channel Form I have tried to load ingredients with exp:channel:entries - but it only gets the entry_id / title from the entry being updated in the form.

I can't figure out how the tag is build...

ex.:

```
    < select multiple name="field_id_12[rows][new_row_0][col_id_4][data][]">
        {dishes}
             {ingredients:entry_id} +
        {/dishes}
    < /select>
```

Anyone who has the knowledge? :-)

THX

Answer (score 1):

Ha, not sure if this is exactly what you want, but I was able to once map out how to tie relationships to a grid for our company.  I hope this helps:

```
{field group:field label}
      {field group:field label: grid field name 1} --> one item
      {field group:field label: grid field name 2} --> another item
{/field group:field label}
```